# how to set display time of ToastMessage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toast

```
  setTimeout(function () { showToastMessage("Guest added successfully test2").fadeOut(4000);});
```

I want to display this message up to 5 sec. but i don't know how to set the display time.
I know how to set the delay time. i have used .fade Out method but its not working. i am still in trouble. help me

I want to display this message up to 5 sec. but i don't know how to set the display time.
I know how to set the delay time. i have used .fade Out method but its not working. i am still in trouble. help me

Comment: i am using this in jquery Mobile project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how work showToastMessage function, but it's looks like this function return jQuery object, so you can use [.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method

```
showToastMessage("Guest added successfully test2")
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(4000);
```

or without jQuery magic you can save jQuery toast object and call fadeOut after timeout

```
var $toast = showToastMessage("Guest added successfully test2");
setTimeout(function(){
    $toast.fadeOut(4000);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can customise the JQuery toaster as you want, it to be.

Not just the time but the look and feel as well, by passing toaster settings as below

> $.toaster({ settings : {...} });

For example to set the timeout property you can pass below argument,

> $.toaster({ settings : {'timeout': 5000} });

This setting just need to be done only once.You can change the settings at any moment.

Or you can clear all custom changes and revert to the default settings as below

> $.toaster.reset();

For other settings options you can [visit this link](https://github.com/scottoffen/jquery.toaster).